# MFC Application: launch a (modal) dialog from a form button

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2013, mfc, dialog

I'm completely new at this and I'm trying to use VS2013 and C++ and loosely follow "Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2010" to figure out how windows form apps and dialogs work. I seem to be miserably failing at figuring out something that should be extremely simple.

I've made a form, `MyForm`, added a button to it, `IDD_DIALOG1`.

I also created a dialog, `MyFirstDialog`.

I want to be able to launch `MyFirstDialog` when I click on `IDD_DIALOG1`.

The book talks about event handlers, but I can't seem to find a way to get to any, so instead I have been trying to add code in the `button1_Click` function in `MyForm.h`:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             MyFirstDialog dlg;
             dlg.DoModal();
}
```

However, this completely breaks my program, with an assertion failure:

[image: Assertion Failed]

I've looked online but I wasn't able to figure it out at all...

Comment: MFC isn't WinForms, I've never tried combining the two but I don't imagine they'd work well together.

Comment: Oh, maybe that's why I can't find anything about this online...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I believe @The Forest And The Trees is right in his comment above, and WinForms don't work well with MFC.

I am switching over to pure MFC now.